# Calculate inverse of normal function that minimizes another function

Tags: java, math, statistics

I have implemented a method (`Normal.compute()`) that calculates the sum of two normal function:

```
public class Normal {
    private double mu1, mu2;
    private double sigma1, sigma2;

    public double compute(double x, double y) {
        return normal(x,mu1,sigma1) + normal(y,mu2,sigma2);
    }

    public double normal(double x, double mu, double sigma) {
        return Math.pow(Math.E, (-1*Math.pow((x-mu),2)) /   (2* Math.pow(sigma,2))
                        /
                        sigma * Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI)
        );
    }

    public static double distance(double ax1, double ax2, double bx1, double bx2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((bx1-ax1),2)+Math.pow((bx2-ax2),2));
    }

}
```

Now fixed a value `z` and a point `(x1,y1)`, I would retrieve the nearest (in terms of distance) point for which the value of `Normal.compute() = z`.
Where nearest is computed by `distance()`.

So what I need is to calculate the inverse function and minimize the distance, but I don't know how do it programmatically.

```
public double[] inverseNearest(double z, double x1, double x2) {
    // K = Set of (x,y) such that compute(x,y) = z

    // return argmin { distance(xk, yk, x1, x2) for each (xk, yk) in K }
}
```

I've tried to use apache common math or colt, but they don't seem helpful.

This is not an exercise, so I can use a library if there is something already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can phrase this as optimizing a function nested inside finding a root.

Optimization problem: find `max_t normal.compute(foo(t))` where `foo(t)` parametrizes a circle of radius `r` centered on `(x1, y1)`, i.e. `foo(t) = [x1 + r cos(t), y1 + r sin(t)]`. (Use `max` if `normal.compute(x1, y1)` is less than `z`. Otherwise use `min`.)

Root finding problem: find `r` such that the solution to the optimization problem = `z`.

I got this idea by looking at a contour plot of `normal.compute(x, y)` and thinking about circles around `(x1, y1)`. The value of `normal.compute` goes up and down as you walk around the circle. You want the circle such that its highest or lowest point is exactly `z`. Hope this helps.

EDIT: I like this question, so I've constructed a solution. Here is a script for the Maxima [1] computer algebra system. See comments in the code. Have fun.

```
/* solve problem stated in:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099321/calculate-inverse-of-normal-function-that-minimizes-another-function
 *
 * copyright 2014 by Robert Dodier
 * I release this work under terms of the GNU General Public License
 *
 * how to:
 *
 * (1) assign values to m1, s1, m2, s2, x1, y1, and z0
 * (2) batch("foo.mac");
 *
 * example:
 *
 * [m1, s1, m2, s2, x1, y1, z0] : [-2, 1.8, 1.3, 2.4, 1.82, -0.24, 0.3];
 * batch ("foo.mac");
 *  => [x0, y0] = [- .4249300563696112, 0.172672148095035]
 *
 * after that, try:
 *
 * set_plot_option ([same_xy, true]);
 * load (implicit_plot);
 * implicit_plot ([F (x, y) = z0, (x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2 = r0^2], [x, -5, 5], [y, -5, 5]), numer;
 *
 * should show z0 contour just touching the circle of radius r0 centered on [x1, y1]
 */

load (distrib);
ratprint : false;

/* m1, s1, m2, s2 must be assigned values */

F (x, y) := pdf_normal (x, m1, s1) + pdf_normal (y, m2, s2);

/* x1, y1 must be assigned values */

G (r, x1, y1) := fmax_circular (lambda ([t], F (x1 + r * cos (t), y1 + r * sin (t))));

fmax_circular (f) := lmax (map (f, fargmax_circular (f)));

fargmax_circular (f) := block ([n : 17, u0, u2],
  map (f, makelist (i * 2 * float (%pi) / n, i, 0, n)),
  ev (sublist_indices (%%, lambda ([u], u = u_max)), u_max = lmax (%%)),
  map (lambda ([i], [u0, u2] : [(i - 1) * 2 * float (%pi) / n, (i + 1) * 2 * float (%pi) / n], fargmax1 (f, u0, u2)), %%));

/* golden section search */

fargmax1 (f, u0, u2) := block ([tol : 1e-2, u1 : u0 + (u2 - u0) / float (%phi)],
  while u2 - u0 > tol
    do block ([x],
      if u2 - u1 > u1 - u0
        then x : u1 + (1 - 1/float (%phi)) * (u2 - u1)
        else x : u1 - (1 - 1/float (%phi)) * (u1 - u0),
      if f(x) > f(u1)
        then /* accept interval containing x */
          if u2 - u1 > u1 - u0
            then [u0, u1, u2] : [u1, x, u2]
            else [u0, u1, u2] : [u0, x, u1]
        else /* reject interval containing x */
          if u2 - u1 > u1 - u0
            then [u0, u1, u2] : [u0, u1, x]
            else [u0, u1, u2] : [x, u1, u2]),
  u0 + (u1 - u0) / 2);

/* z0 must be assigned a value */

r0 : find_root (lambda ([r], G (r, x1, y1) - z), r, 0.001, 5), z = z0, numer;

/* fargmax_circular returns a list -- assume it's just one element
 * not guaranteed to work -- [t0] : ... fails when rhs has 2 or more elements, oh well
 */
[t0] : fargmax_circular (lambda ([t], F (x1 + r0 * cos (t), y1 + r0 * sin (t))));

/* [x0, y0] is the point on z0 contour of F, nearest to [x1, y1]
 * r0 is distance from [x1, y1] to [x0, y0]
 */

[x0, y0] : [x1 + r0 * cos (t0), y1 + r0 * sin (t0)];

F (x0, y0), numer; /* should be equal to z0 */
```

Comment: I tried your solution with maxima and it works perfectly thanks. I would upvote you more than once if I could :) I'm just having some trouble to translate it in java, but I hope I will do it

Comment: @marka.thore Well, the code has some Maxima idiosyncrasies in it; I hope those aren't too distracting. I think if you focus on the overall design (min/max within root finding) you will be able to convert it to Java. You might be able to find suitable functions for the min/max and root finding parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
normal(x,mu1,sigma1) + normal(y,mu2,sigma2)
```

That is not the correct way to compute the probability of the sum of two normally distributed random variables. If your x and y are drawn from two *independent* normal distributions, call them X and Y, then the sum X+Y is in turn normally distributed. The mean of Z=X+Y is the sum of the two means, and the square of the variance is the sum of the squares of the two variances.

In other words, you should be using

```
normal(x+y,mu1+mu2,Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sigma1,2)+Math.pow(sigma,2)))
```

Comment: thank you, but I'm not calculating the sum of two normally distributed random variables. That function represents the utility of a point `(x,y)` for an agent. So the utility is max (`2`) when `x=mu1` and `y=mu2`, and that is ok for me